# How do I bind gradient to object so that it doesn't change when I move the object?

Tags: inkscape, gradient

Typical situation.

1. Make an object in gradient:
   [image: image description]
2. Move the object:

   [image: image description]
3. Uninstall Inskcape.

My question therefore is, whether I can bind the gradient to the object so that it moves when I move the object, resizes when I resize the object and generally acts as background, not invisible object I cannot control.

Comment: To me the typical situation would rather be: Select the object -> move it -> undo because the wrong object was moved --> zoom to try to select the right object by clicking at random locations near the object --> unzoom --> move --> the object has disappeared because color is now the end of the gradient with alpha zero --> undo --> launch Google to understand, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a switch for exactly this:

[image: Move gradients (in fill or stroke) along with the objects]